# NPM command not working - ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, mkdir

Tags: npm

npm command suddenly stopped working. Not sure what i have done wrong. Tried re installing still it fails

```
USBLRAVIVEKMB3:teach avivek$ npm
Error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, mkdir '/Users/avivek/Dev/Node/Experiments/teach/(node:4125) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
(node:4125) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
(node:4125) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
/usr/local'
    at Error (native)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/3899#issuecomment-580394612

In the root folder of your project create a `.dockerignore` file and add this line:
`cdk*`